# magento join entity id with product sku from query result

Tags: mysql, magento

hi i'm running the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` WHERE `value` LIKE '%knife%' OR `value` LIKE '%Knife%' OR `value` LIKE '%KNIFE%' OR `value` LIKE '%razor%' OR `value` LIKE '%Razor%' OR `value` LIKE '%RAZOR%'
```

I wasnt sure if the column was case senitive

this pulls all the results with entity ids but thats useless for me i need product sku's how can i achieve this in the results i'm assuming i have to join but what table and how.

so the result i'd like to see is the product sku that matches my search criteria on the description

thanks

solved it with this

select p.entity_id, p.sku, a.entity_id as description_id, a.value from catalog_product_entity p inner join catalog_product_entity_text a on p.entity_id = a.entity_id WHERE a.value LIKE '%knife%' OR a.value LIKE '%Knife%' OR a.value LIKE '%KNIFE%'

not sure if this is the most efficient way to do this though

on a DB with over 200,000 products and descriptions with large amounts of text

also not sure if this accounts for everything in the magento DB

Answer (score 0):

**Lets' try this statement. I think it can help you:**

```
select *
from catalog_product_entity_text
where LOWER(value) LIKE LOWER('%aBcDeF%');
```

Comment: That won't work - you have applied the wild card to the wrong side of the test! (and no point in converting a lower case string 'aaaaa' into lower case!)

Comment: @LordPeter, it's just an example. We can put anything in it

Answer (score 0):

For extracting product `sku`, use `entity_id` (*from your SQL query result*) to search for `sku` from `catalog_product_entity` table.

Like this:

`SELECT sku from catalog_product_entity WHERE entity_id=23123`

Comment: this table was all i really needed to know thanks  i used this select p.entity_id, p.sku, a.entity_id as description_id, a.value from catalog_product_entity p inner join catalog_product_entity_text a on p.entity_id = a.entity_id WHERE a.value LIKE '%knife%' OR a.value LIKE '%Knife%' OR a.value LIKE '%KNIFE%'

Comment: select as an answer